# How to tell python to run a .py file when both a .pyc and .py file are present?

Tags: python, pyc

I have a project that I have compiled into .pyc files for security, but I want to be able to drop a .py file into my project for debugging purposes as necessary. How can I tell python to use a .py file if both the .py and .pyc files are present in a folder?

i.e. I have:

```
main:
   |
   run.pyc
   /src/
      |
      dependency1.pyc
      dependency2.pyc
      dependency2.py
      dependency3.pyc
```

and when both `dependency2.pyc` and `dependency2.py` are in `/src/` I want `run.pyc` to use `dependency2.py`.

Comment: There is no "security" in .pyc files. They can be decompiled trivially.

Comment: Is there a way to better secure the compiled files so that they cannot be decompiled?

Comment: I believe the `.pyc` file contains the timestamp of the `.py` it was generated from, and if that is different from the timestamp of the `.py` file currently in the directory, it will use the `.py` file.  So, it should do what you want already.

Comment: _Is there a way to better secure the compiled files_ You can package the whole application into a standalone `.exe` file, but that comes with its own headaches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to debugging.

From Python docs:

> Python will ignore all legacy pyc files when a source file exists next to it. In other words, if a foo.pyc file exists next to the foo.py file, the pyc file will be ignored in all cases

In your case, `run.py` should be using `dependency2.py` and ignoring the associated `pyc`, which in turn should allow you to debug.

If that's not happening, try to temporarily move the compiled file `dependency2.pyc` out of the directory.